# Use java streams to convert List of SimpleEntry of brandName and Product to a map of brandName to List of Products

Tags: java, java-stream

I am looking to convert a list of `SimpleEntry<String, Product>` to a `Map<String, List<Product>`. The string is brandName and each brandName has products. So, I want to convert `List<SimpleEntry<>` to `Map<String, List<Product>` where in the map, I get a list of products for a brandName.

Currently, I am using the following code but I think this can be done with streams too

```
//List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Product>> listOfSimpleEntries = new ArrayList<>() is a list of simple Entries 
//e.g. 
//nike, productA 
//adidas, productB,
//nike, productC

Map<String, List<Product>> brandToProductsMap = new HashMap<>();
for (AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Product> simpleEntry : listOfSimpleEntries) {
    if (!brandToProductsMap.containsKey(simpleEntry.getKey())) {
        brandToProductsMap.put(simpleEntry.getKey(), new ArrayList<>());
    }
    brandToProductsMap.get(simpleEntry.getKey()).add(simpleEntry.getValue());
}
```

I tried to replace the above code with the streams like below but I am getting the **java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to Product**

```
Map<String, List<Product>> brandToProductsMap = listOfSimpleEntries.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
          w -> w.getKey(), Collectors.mapping(x -> x.getValue(), Collectors.toList())));
```

Can someone please point me what I am missing here? Thanks.

**Edit 2**
The code I wrote works as a separate program but not part of the project. I found that in the target folder, the code is compiled as below which does not seem right.

```
        Map<String, List<Product>> brandToProductsMap = (Map)listOfSimpleEntries.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy((w) -> {
            return (String)w.getKey();
        }, Collectors.mapping((x) -> {
            return (Product)x.getValue();
        }, Collectors.toList())));
        Iterator var5 = brandToProductsMap .entrySet().iterator();
```

Comment: assuming `CompatibleProduct` is a typo for `Product`, this is not reproducible.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Product>> entries = Arrays.asList(
        new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("Nike", new Product("ProductA")),
        new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("Adidas", new Product("ProductB")),
        new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("Nike", new Product("ProductC"))
);

Map<String, List<Product>> brandNameToProduct = entries.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(), 
                Collectors.mapping(e -> e.getValue(), Collectors.toList())));

System.out.println(brandNameToProduct);
```

Output:

```
{Nike=[Product(name=ProductA), Product(name=ProductC)], Adidas=[Product(name=ProductB)]}
```

### EDIT:

I think you did exactly the same like me, so perhaps your IDE went crazy.

Comment: Yah, I did exactly the same and if I run it as a separate program, it works fine but not as the part of the project. I don't know what is the problem with my intelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

Hope that my code snippet below could help:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<SimpleEntry<String, Product>> list = new ArrayList<SimpleEntry<String, Product>>();
        list.add(SimpleEntry.of("electronic", new Product(1, "SmartPhone")));
        list.add(SimpleEntry.of("electronic", new Product(2, "Laptop")));
        list.add(SimpleEntry.of("office", new Product(3, "Book")));
        list.add(SimpleEntry.of("office", new Product(4, "Pencil")));
        list.add(SimpleEntry.of("office", new Product(5, "Notes")));
        list.add(SimpleEntry.of("garden", new Product(6, "Rosesmany")));
        list.add(SimpleEntry.of("garden", new Product(7, "Soil Mix")));
        list.add(SimpleEntry.of("garden", new Product(8, "Pressure Sprayer")));
        
        System.out.println("Before:");
        list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        
        Map<String, List<Product>> map = list.stream().collect(
                    groupingBy(entry -> entry.getKey(), mapping(entry -> entry.getEntry(), toList())) 
                );
        
        System.out.println("After:");
        map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Key : " + k + ", Value : " + v));
}
```

SimpleEntry

```
public class SimpleEntry<K, V> {
    private K key;
    private V entry;
        
    static public <K, V> SimpleEntry<K, V> of (K key, V entry)
    {
        SimpleEntry<K, V> sEntry = new SimpleEntry<>();
        sEntry.setKey(key);
        sEntry.setEntry(entry);
        return sEntry;
    }
    //getters/setters...
}
```

I wrote it and it worked for me:

```
Before:
electronic - Product(1, SmartPhone)
electronic - Product(2, Laptop)
office - Product(3, Book)
office - Product(4, Pencil)
office - Product(5, Notes)
garden - Product(6, Rosesmany)
garden - Product(7, Soil Mix)
garden - Product(8, Pressure Sprayer)
After:
Key : electronic, Value : [Product(1, SmartPhone), Product(2, Laptop)]
Key : garden, Value : [Product(6, Rosesmany), Product(7, Soil Mix), Product(8, Pressure Sprayer)]
Key : office, Value : [Product(3, Book), Product(4, Pencil), Product(5, Notes)]
```

Comment: Thanks Howie. You code works and mine and the one added by Most Needed Rabbit works too when executed in a separate class, but as part of the project, I am getting error message. So, I am trying to figure out what settings I need to change to make it correct.